# problem in using total with buttons and radio buttons

Tags: java

i am doing a program as for ordering ice cream and the user first should choose between cone or cups (as buttons) and when he clicks the button the total shows in the Text field, and then he can proceed to choose the flavor  as checkbox and the total will add whenever he add an extra flavor and so on

the problem is that when i start clicking the buttons it shows the total but when i choose a flavor the total doesnt add it got replaced by the price of the flavor and when i go back to choose a cone or cup then it will add the price of what i chose to the total

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String a = e.getActionCommand();
         total = 0;
         if(a.equals("cone")){
                total = (total +7); 
            t1.setText(Double.toString(total));

        } else if(a.equals("cup")){
                total = (total +5); 
            t1.setText(Double.toString(total));

            }
        if(RB3.isSelected()){

        total = total +7; 
            t1.setText(Double.toString(total));

        }
        if(RB2.isSelected()){

                total = (total +7); 
            t1.setText(Double.toString(total));

        }if(RB1.isSelected()){

                total = (total +7); 
            t1.setText(Double.toString(total));
```

here is the code for the actionPerformed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `total` to 0 at the beginining of the action routine program. If you want it to reflect a value that it had prior to clicking a button, you're going to need to declare it outside the routine so that it still has the previous value when you add to it.

EDIT: I see that you add for cone and cup after you set `total` to 0, but only if the action command indicates that the user chose one on this action. If the action command is different than cone or cup when they choose a flavor, then the total will stay 0; otherwise total will get the value for either cup or cone. That might not be the same value `total` had before the action.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Now a word about StackOverflow -- when you find any answer helpful, upvote it. For the earliest answer that answers your question, click on the checkmark next to that answer to mark it as "the answer". This helps other people searching for similar answers, and increases reputation for people who volunteer their time to help other folks out.